# Unknown array size C# - compression

Tags: c#, arrays, resize, compression, size

I am implementing compression algorithm in C#. Problem is that i don't know file size before compression. What is the best way to solve this? Of course i store compressed data into array, but i don't know its size before compression.

Comment: Can you give us more details and pay attention to details such as when you want compression and decompression ? It's kind of confusing that you want to compress a file but you don't know the size of it uncompressed. Before compression you can know the size of the data you want to compress but you can't know the size of the compressed data.

Comment: I meant the size of compressed file...I can't know it before compression process is done.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried so that I can adjust the solution I have in mind to your needs.

Comment: @user216799 so you don't know what size you should give  to your array,is that the problem?

Comment: Please spend some time to **read FAQ** and tips about how a good question should be wrote. It'll help you to get better answers and it will help us to don't think you're too lazy even to spend some time to describe what you need...

Comment: yeah Selman22 that is a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
    byte[] CompressByteArray(byte[] uncompressedData)
    {
        byte[] compressedData;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                // dummy compression algorithm
                for (int i = 0; i < uncompressedData.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    var newByte = uncompressedData[0] + uncompressedData[1];
                    writer.Write(newByte);
                }
            }

            ms.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            compressedData = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return compressedData;
    }
```

However it is very inefficient. You should also have the input file as a stream, not as a byte array if you don't want your memory to be filled. Basically you need to read from a stream and write to another (perhaps the MemoryStream should actually be a stream to a file so that you write directly on a temporary file on the disk when you are compressing big files).

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the uncompressed file, you should use the `System.IO.FileInfo` class, which has a Length property for the size of the file in bytes.

I would use this plus 10% for the size of the holding array[s] as the majority of the time, the compressed file will be smaller but there are occasions where the 'compressed' file is actually larger than the original (e.g. is you try to compress a file that is already compressed). Before use, ensure the output array is initialised to NULLs.

The size of the output file will be the size of the output array minus the list of NULLs at the end.

Herbie

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Generic lists` instead of Arrays if you don't know the array size:

```
List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
```

Then you don't need to set list size,it will grow automatically as long as you add new items.

Comment: +1 actually it's right even if I wouldn't use a list and I wouldn't even keep all data in memory (unless it's a requirement).

Answer (score -1):

The size of the compressed data can only be guessed from the size of the input data, newer really known. You should use a dynamic array (or equivalent) for the output data. Be aware that the output size may as well be *larger* than the input data.

Comment: Yeah man but i can't know will it be 2 times bigger size, 3 times less  size, etc. Also, i avoid using resizing of arrays because i am not sure how fast it is.

Comment: Most likely, you would have (depending on the algorithm) an upper bound of at most 2 times the input size. But if you start with a buffer, say half the size of the input, you'd at most change the size twice. That shouldn't hurt performance